# URI to review the app in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, review

I am a bit confused... I have researched about URLs to use for sending users to the review page on the app store

I have tried:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=842516162&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&type=Purple+Software&mt=8
```

and also:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id842516162
```

I have an iPad (4th gen) and latest iPod, on the iPad it works correctly, on the iPod it comes up with a blank page.

Both are running 7.1.1

What do I need to do to get it to work on the ipod touch?

Comment: Can you see the app details on this device if navigated manually ?

Comment: It seems a reboot a couple of times seems to be have rectified it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=842516162"; 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```